# Why am I getting req.isXHubValid is not a function

Tags: node.js, express

I'm configuring a route on express like this:

```
router.post('/my route', xhub({ algorithm: 'sha1', secret: APP_SECRET }), function (req, res, next) {
req.isXHubValid()
```

When I do this I'm getting

TypeError: req.isXHubValid is not a function

Ps: I'm requiring express-x-hub like `const xhub = require('express-x-hub')`

Does anyone know how can I solve this? Thank you so much!

Comment: Are you passing it as middleware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope that except for the require you are registering it as well. [The example here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-x-hub):

```
var xhub = require('express-x-hub');
app.use(xhub({ algorithm: 'sha1', secret: XHUB_SECRET_HERE }));
app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(methodOverride());
```

***UPDATE***

If you read carefully the documentation:

> Then add the middleware to Express.js. It needs to be one of the first
>   and before bodyParser().

So, definitely registering at the context of your post route it will not work.